# Convert spaces to %20 in list

Tags: python, urlencode

I need to convert spaces to %20 for api posts in a python array

```
tree = et.parse(os.environ['SPRINT_XML'])
olp = tree.findall(".//string")
if not olp:
  print colored('FAILED', 'red') +" No jobs accociated to this view"
  exit(1)
joblist = [t.text for t in olp]
```

How can I do that to t.text above?

Comment: seems a double question to me. do you know how to convert a single element?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote

Comment: What about other characters, shouldn't they be URL encoded as well?

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want to url encode, or simply replace spaces?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `String.replace()` method as described here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

So for `t.text`, it would be `t.text.replace(" ", "%20")`

Comment: Works perfect and is way less convoluted than the above answers. Don't know why everyone thinks urllib is so necessary to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Jordan If the user's intent is to use a dynamic URL, it is more secure to escape the entire string, rather than replacing multiple occurrences of a single character.

Comment: The `urllib` answer is, arguably, preferable because it makes your intent clearer: you are URL-encoding the string. Replacing spaces with `%20` is *how* you are doing it (assuming spaces are the only thing you need to worry about). Writing code that explains itself is better.

Comment: Thanks, this actually does what I want the urllib replaces s space with a +, not what I wanted.

Answer (score 54):

I would recommend using `urllib.parse` module and its `quote()` function.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote
Example for Python3:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
text_encoded = quote(t.text)
```

Note: using `quote_plus()` won't work in your case as this function replaces spaces by plus char.

Comment: urllib has no module named parse

Comment: @TylerR yes, it has
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Comment: urllib.quote in python 2

Comment: The OP's code is in Python 2, as you can see from the `print` statement.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is more pythonic

Answer (score 7):

Use [urllib.quote_plus](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) for this:

```
import urllib

...

joblist = [urllib.quote_plus(t.text) for t in olp]
```

Comment: and in python 3 [`urllib.parse.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus)

Answer (score -1):

Here is something I found that might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqxKQbKTO7o

```py
    def spaceReplace(s):
        strArr = list(s)
        for i, c in enumerate(strArr):
            if c == ' ': strArr[i] = '%20'
        return "".join(strArr)
    
    df["Name"] = df["Name"].apply(spaceReplace)
```